# INVALID NUMBER ERROR WHIE USING TO_NUMBER

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR( TO_DATE(SUBSTR(UPDATED_DATE,1,8),'DD/MM/RRRR'),'RRRR MM DD')) FROM tw_edu_infra_amenities;

SELECT TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR( TO_DATE(SUBSTR(UPDATED_DATE,1,8),'DD/MM/RRRR'),'RRRRMMDD')) AS NEW_DATE FROM tw_edu_infra_amenities;
```

First query is not working and second one is working just by removing the spaces in date format in to_char.why?

Answer (score 2):

Because - when you applied format model `RRRR MM DD` - it results in a value such as `2023 02 23`. If you apply `TO_NUMBER` to it, you get an error:

```
SQL> select to_number('2023 02 23') result from dual;
select to_number('2023 02 23') result from dual
                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Without spaces in format model, value is `20230223` which *can* be converted to a valid number:

```
SQL> select to_number('20230223') result from dual;

    RESULT
----------
  20230223

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

For what I understood you need, I think you should use the extract function.

```
select to_char(extract(year from date_updated))||' '||
  to_char(extract(month from date_updated),'00')||' '||
  to_char(extract(day from date_updated),'00')
from x_table;
```